# numpy only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy

```
import random
random.randint(0, 255)
array_xx= np.full((255), random.randint(0, 255))
array_yy= np.full((255), random.randint(0, 255))
array_col= np.full((255), random.randint(0, 255))
plt.plot(array_xx,array_yy, c='#00'+'{:02x}'.format(int(array_col*255),2)+'00')
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to make plt.plot take color values from array_col, but
tells me:

```
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: error is here `int(array_col*255)` What are you trying to do?

Comment: did you read below the code? I'm trying to make plt.plot take color values from array_col for green of rgb.

Comment: I'm asking what are you trying to do with that specific piece of code? `array_col` is already integers. You **cannot** convert the entire array to an `int`. At least that's what `int()` does.

Comment: if i don't put int (), '{:02x}'.format () will throw another error, you can try it in colab, where i am running.

Comment: `c='#00'+'{:02x}'.format(int(array_col*255),2)+'00'` only works if `array_col` is a single number.  `int` is the first thing to complain if you give an array, but the `format` will too.  Is this `c` parameter supposed to be one 'color' or an array of them?  If an array this not the way to construct it.